# Shell script to run Python program with command line arguments

Tags: python

I have some files in a directory which are input files for my python script:

```
<1.in>
<1.in.xml>
<2.in>
<2.in.xml>
<3.in>
<3.in.xml>
...
..
.
```

I have the following till now:

```
for i in $(ls dir/*.in)
do
        new = ${i%%.in}
        test.py -i $new.in.xml -o out_$new -x $new.in -c 56
done
```

When I run this, it does not create an output file (which is defined with -o option). 
The error is :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you manually tried something like `test.py -i 1.in.xml -o out_1 -x 1.in -c 56` ?  would help you narrow down the problem

Comment: Show us the test.py code

Comment: Yes I did it manually... It runs fine when I run the python code with a single input file!!!

Comment: then id have to guess `new` doesnt have the value you expect.  can you try to echo out `new` right after you assign to it in each iteration?

Comment: tried that also.... It gives me the value that I want it to take !!!

Comment: in the python program - it takes the output file as: out=open(out,'w'). I now tried something like --- out=out_$new, and then used "out" in test.py command ! I was able to run the program doing this.... However, I am not able to make out where the output files will be stored ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are opening the file for output as open(file_name, 'w') or else the file will not be created.

Comment: I am opening the file as you suggested!